# Wordpress Content Security Policy and Subresource Integrity

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, security

I have tested my website at https://observatory.mozilla.org/ and I receive the following two errors:

1. Content Security Policy     -25 Content Security Policy (CSP) header not implemented
2. Subresource Integrity       -5  Subresource Integrity (SRI) not implemented, but all external scripts are loaded over HTTPS

I've been trying to fix it all morning, but there's no way to do it. If anyone has any idea how this can be solved in WordPress I know how grateful. I have tried several plugins and also to work on .htacces but everything I get as a resource, makes the web go down.
Anyone have any idea? Thank you

Comment: Way too broad of a question IMHO. Especially in a WP setting, where you are probably dealing with a lot of 3rd-party plugins / themes that did not prepare for this from the start, and might spill JS code into the document in any number of different ways, this is probably going to take some work. _“I have tried several plugins”_ is way too naive and basic of an approach here, I think. This needs careful analyzing of what violations occur and where first of all.

Comment: @04FS Nono, the WordPress template is developed by me, the web only uses 4 basic plugings. The point is that I had never had to expand this, and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The templates by defects are deactivated and deleted so that they do not generate any type of problems

Comment: _“and I don't know how to do it”_ - which “it” in particular? How CSP and SRI work, what info you need to provide and where, you can go read up on.